# .NET CORE 2.1 Websocket Ping/Pong

Tags: .net, websocket, ping

I have created a middleware on .NET CORE 2.1 which listens for incoming websockets connections (handshakes).

The problem is that when a client sends to my server a Ping frame, my Server can not respond with Pong, and after 30 seconds, the client disconnects because he did not receive any Pong.

In Websocket settings there settings for interval of Ping, but as I understood - it enables server side Pinging, but how do I can enable that my Server will respond with Pong?

Answer (score 0):

Without code it's hard to tell what could be wrong.

Take a look at; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers

Comment: For instance, To get messages I am using System.Net.WebSockets.ReceiveAsync(ArraySegment<byte> buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken). But it only handles messages that a client sends, but not ping frames itself. 
Other possibility is that I am using Azure and this one isn't allowing to send frames

Comment: It looks like you are having the same issue as https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3128